# Timer count down and div checking opacity before starting timer? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

Heres the code Duno why it isn't working.

```
    <div id="Timer5min"></div>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="message phrase1 helvetica">late one christmas morn'...</div>
        <div class="message phrase2 helvetica">all of the fragorian children were sleeping...</div>
        <div class="message phrase3 helvetica">but there was one little hero who could not wait...</div>
        <div class="message phrase4 helvetica" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 0;"></div>
    </div>
```

js

```
var timer = 301; // 5 minutes worth of seconds + 1 for the first call    
function countDown() {
    if (--timer) {
        var minutes = timer % 60;
        if (!minutes) {
            minutes = '00';
        }
        $('#Timer5min').text(Math.floor(timer / 60) + ':' + minutes);
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    } else {
        window.location = 'http://google.com';
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = setInterval(function () {           
        if($('.phrase4').css('opacity') == 0) {    
            alert();
            countDown();    
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

I assume its the  if statment as i dont get an alert any ideas where iv gone wrong.?
nothing is happening 
what is ment to happen is it checks the opacity once the opacity is matching it plays the count down timer...

Comment: i dont understand the selector `is(': inherit')`

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? What are you seeing it do? Are there any errors in the console of your browser? The more information you can provide about the issue, the better prepared we are to try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that `setTimeout(countDown, 1000);` since the function is already called inside a `setInterval`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/e3n7ydy5/). is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

"setTimeout(countDown, 1000);" and setInterval only one; I test by chrome, that's ok.